# CSS3 transition on matrix transformation with jQuery on FF/Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I've written a simple little transition animation that on page load should reveal the content a little like the opening of a window blind.  It uses a combination of css3, to set the transition values, and jQuery to apply a change to the transform: matrix values on page load.  It works fine in Safari, but for the life of me I can't grasp why the transition effect doesn't work on FF or Chrome.  In both those browsers, the 'blind' just disappears to reveal the content after the transition display, rather than transitioning out in four vertical strips as it should.

Code below, I've also put this is a fiddle here (which, as I say works in Safari, so you can see the sort of effect I'm expecting):

https://jsfiddle.net/ebenezer66/783uh6k3/

The basic html:

```
<div class="home__columnShades__div">
  <div class="home__columnShades__div__column">
    <div class="home__columnShades__div__columnOne"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="home__columnShades__div__column">
    <div class="home__columnShades__div__columnTwo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="home__columnShades__div__column">
    <div class="home__columnShades__div__columnThree"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="home__columnShades__div__column">
    <div class="home__columnShades__div__columnFour"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.home__columnShades__div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 899;
}

.home__columnShades__div__column {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnOne {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: transform 3s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnTwo {
  @extend .home__columnShades__div__columnOne;
  left: 25%;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnThree {
  @extend .home__columnShades__div__columnOne;
  left: 50%;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnFour {
  @extend .home__columnShades__div__columnOne;
  left: 75%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  var viewWidthQuarter = $(window).width() / 4;

  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnOne').css({
    'transform': 'matrix(0, 0, 0, 1, -' + viewWidthQuarter / 1.5 + ', 0)'
  });
  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnTwo').css({
    'background-position': '-' + viewWidthQuarter + 'px' + ' 0',
    'transform': 'matrix(0, 0, 0, 1, -' + viewWidthQuarter / 1.5 + ', 0)'
  });
  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnThree').css({
    'background-position': '-' + viewWidthQuarter * 2 + 'px' + ' 0',
    'transform': 'matrix(0, 0, 0, 1, -' + viewWidthQuarter / 1.5 + ', 0)'
  });
  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnFour').css({
    'background-position': '-' + viewWidthQuarter * 3 + 'px' + ' 0',
    'transform': 'matrix(0, 0, 0, 1, -' + viewWidthQuarter / 1.5 + ', 0)'
  });
```

Comment: After playing around a little, the code works if I just perform the transform on scaleX, but I wanted to use matrix so as to use translate to gradually move each vertical to the left (so it appears they're fading to the left, rather than to the centre just using scale).

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't solved why transform: matrix (or translate) won't work on FF/Chrome, I've reworked my code to use a transition on the left position of each vertical blind instead of transform's translate value.  It actually even works a bit better - the animation is definitely smoother.

https://jsfiddle.net/ebenezer66/ttgp8bj4/

Updated jQuery:

```
  var viewWidth = $(window).width(),
  viewWidthQuarter = viewWidth / 4;

  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnOne').css({
    'left': viewWidth-(viewWidthQuarter*4.5) + 'px',
    'transform': 'scaleX(0)'
  });
  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnTwo').css({
    'background-position': '-' + viewWidthQuarter + 'px' + ' 0',
    'left': viewWidth-(viewWidthQuarter*3.5) + 'px',
    'transform': 'scaleX(0)'
  });
  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnThree').css({
    'background-position': '-' + viewWidthQuarter * 2 + 'px' + ' 0',
    'left': viewWidth-(viewWidthQuarter*2.5) + 'px',
    'transform': 'scaleX(0)'
  });
  $('.home__columnShades__div__columnFour').css({
    'background-position': '-' + viewWidthQuarter * 3 + 'px' + ' 0',
    'left': viewWidth-(viewWidthQuarter*1.5) + 'px',
    'transform': 'scaleX(0)'
  });
```

Updated CSS:

```
.home__columnShades__div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 899;
}

.home__columnShades__div__column {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnOne {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: transform 3s, left 3s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnTwo {
  @extend .home__columnShades__div__columnOne;
  left: 25%;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnThree {
  @extend .home__columnShades__div__columnOne;
  left: 50%;
}

.home__columnShades__div__columnFour {
  @extend .home__columnShades__div__columnOne;
  left: 75%;
}
```